# Why does html disappar when trying to iterate using for loop in django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am having an issue where I have categories for each product, so for my URLs, i have slugs referencing to each category. in the href on my frontpage (HTML pasted down below). I see that when I load the portion of the HTML that has the for loop applied makes it disappear. I have never run into this. Does anybody have any idea what's going on? I'll post the relevant div where this is occurring. I can post additional code if needed. Thanks

In this case, the Get covered now button is missing

```
Edsure\apps\core\templates\frontpage.html
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}


<div id="signup">
                {% for category in menu_categories %}
                <a class="btn btn-lg col-sm-12 slideanim" id="title" href="{% url 'category_detail' category.slug %}">
                    Get Covered Now!
                </a>
                {% endfor %}
                <a class="btn btn-lg col-sm-12 slideanim" id="title" href="#">
                    Learn More!
                </a>
            </div>
```

```
Edsure\apps\core\views.py
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from apps.store.models import Product

def frontpage(request):
    return render(request, 'frontpage.html')
```

```
Edsure\apps\store\views.py
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Product, Category

def product_detail(request,category_slug, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)

    context = {
        'product': product
    }

    return render(request, 'product_detail.html', context)

def category_detail(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(category, slug=slug)
    products = category.products.all()

    context = {
        'category': category,
        'products': products
    }
    return render(request,'category_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: can you add the views to the question?

Comment: @taha maatof adding now

Answer (score 0):

so, in your view you have no context named "menu_categories" but "category",try this instead:

```
 {% for c in category %}
            <a class="btn btn-lg col-sm-12 slideanim" id="title" href="{% url 'category_detail' c.slug %}">
                Get Covered Now!
            </a>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The issue actually lied in my custom context processor I created for the categories to allow them to be globally accessible. I did have a follow-up question regarding slugs. instead of using a for loop to iterate each category to dynamically create href is there a way I can call a specific category slug in the href? I can explain more if needed  of course